# Do +1 magic items affect each one of multiple dice rolled for damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage

My DM gave me a magic knife that does 3d6 damage and has +1 on attack rolls. Does that mean I would roll 3d6 and then add 1 to the final result, or would I add 1 for each d6 roll?

Comment: No problem, there is a bit of a learning curve to this site. You might want to take the [tour] (it's quite quick) to find out how things work here, and you can also visit the [help] for more info.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The item you describe sounds like homebrew, which means the only person with an official answer would be the DM who gave it to you.

However, if we take your description literally:

> My Dm gave me a magic knife that does 3d6 damage and has +1 on attack rolls.

Then this weapon does not add *anything* to damage rolls, because you say it adds +1 to "attack rolls" and the damage roll is not one of those.

In the case that this weapon has "+1 on attack and damage rolls", you would add +1 to the *total* damage dealt, because even if the dagger rolls 3 dice for damage, those 3 dice together are still one "damage roll". (Same as if you rolled a critical hit with a normal weapon or swing a Greatsword; you might roll 2 dice for the damage, but it's still only one damage roll and you'd still only add +1 for your magic weapon)

The wording would have to be pretty specific if it added +1 to every die rolled. But, again, this is a homebrew weapon so the only official answer can come from your DM.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning +1 greatswords specifically for the non-homebrew comparison? They're a relevant case where there will often be multiple dice rolled but only one +1 added.

Comment: @LizWeir That's what I was thinking as well, nice catch.